# Ruby on Rails and .NET Continous Integration & Version Control Setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc-3, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm a .NET developer and I've set up a git repository and teamcity on a windows server machine. I'm also starting to use/learn ruby and I'll be wanting to setup some CI for ruby on rails as well.

I was wondering what the best setup for this would be. I've only one machine I can use as a server.

Everything on Windows Server - I expect this will make things difficult for the ruby CI. I'm developing ruby on an Ubuntu VM inside windows 7.

Everything on Ubuntu (or other Linux) server - Big problems for .Net as I mono isn't up to date with some of the newest .net tech I use.

A windows server hosting a virtual Ubuntu server. Git and Ruby CI on the Ubuntu server and teamcity on the windows server.

The last choice is my favourite at the moment. But before investing lots of time in setting it all up I was wondering what others may have done in this situation.

I'd also like to start with some continuous deployment as well.

Comment: How are you going to do your ruby development? On windows, or on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeamCity will run rake tasks just fine. In fact, we use a rake task to package up our .net solution and deploy it. If the deployment is not too complex, sticking with a rake task on a your Windows server is probably fine.

For a more complex scenario you'd probably want a *nix based machine using Capistrano. From what I've read using Capistrano on a Windows machine is very difficult, but I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu inside a VirtualBox on a Windows7 Host and it works perfectly. You don't need windows server os. I skipped all the .NET-stuff, so I don't have any experience in running VisualStudio and VirtualBox parallel on the same box, but in this scenario you should have at least(!) 4 GB RAM and SSD.